# how to remove one of the python installed?

Tags: python, python-install

i have 2 installed python, 3.10.12 and 3.12.0, i want to choose 3.12 and remove the 3.10, but i have the problem when remove it

i ran this command

```bash
sudo apt-get remove python3.10
```

and this what i got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : Depends: python3.10 (>= 3.10.6-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

how to solve this??

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Some system tools are using python 3.10 so you likely won't be able to remove it

Comment: The message is essentially saying, if you're going to uninstall a package (`python3.10`), you have to uninstall its dependencies too (`python3`). But, if this is Ubuntu, you can't uninstall it because the OS depends on it.

Comment: You basically do not want to replace the system Python; that way lies madness. Use a tool like `pyenv` to install your own Python builds completely separately from anything the OS depends on.